# Avoid consuming input in Regex

Tags: python, regex

In Regex, I am given a string **"abbabbabba"** and I have to identify all the sub-strings having the pattern **"abba"** and when I try it this way:

```
import re
a=re.findall(r'abba','abbabbabba')
print(a)
```

I get my out put to be

```
['abba', 'abba']
```

Looking at the given string, there are 3 sub-strings of **'abba'** but only two have been printed. This clearly means that the second sub-string which has its **'a'** already consumed in 1st sub-string isn't allowing the function to identify the 2nd sub-string and hence it is directly jumping to the 3rd sub-string and hence only 2 **'abba'** sub-strings are printed. How to make sure that the input isn't consumed in this way and we get the output accordingly as:

```
['abba', 'abba', 'abba']
```

Comment: `a=re.findall(r'(?=(abba))','abbabbabba')`

Comment: thanks @WiktorStribiżew :) since you have marked this as duplicate, I shall delete this question once you have acknowledged that I have understood this.

Comment: Capturing inside a positive lookahead is a usual way to get overlapping matches.

Comment: @Anurag Don't delete it. If someone queries the title just like you have asked, he will find it easy to get to the original question.